# NetBeans 8.1 won't start WildFly 10 server

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, wildfly, wildfly-10

Sometimes (~20% probability) when starting maven application at NetBeans my WildFly won't start. In console I see infinited loop of messages:

```
2016-06-07 09:04:44,689 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
2016-06-07 09:04:44,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
2016-06-07 09:04:44,783 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Configured system properties:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = utf-8
    file.encoding.pkg 2016-06-07 09:04:43,423 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
2016-06-07 09:04:44,689 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
2016-06-07 09:04:44,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
2016-06-07 09:04:44,783 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Configured system properties:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = utf-8
    file.encoding.pkg 2016-06-07 09:04:43,423 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
2016-06-07 09:04:44,689 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 
...
```

Wildfly mode: standalone-full (default configuration)
OS: Windows 8.1
JDK: Oracle 1.8
VM Options: -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:+UseLargePages  -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=utf-8

What is probably wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I bet that WildFly *does* start, but the console output is garbage. This is a [known bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258436) which is fixed in the nightly builds.

If you don't want to go on a nightly build there are only two options: either restart your IDE if it happens or just close the console-window and use something like tail instead. (I know that this is really bothering that's why I'm currently running a nightly build version (which has other flaws :-/))